# Sync text and audio using html javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Hi i am calling two different web services from my angular script. First service is returning text which i am using as an input to second text to audio service. Since in some case text is long string and it takes time to load the audio file, but meanwhile text output prints on screen. My requirement is to print the text output on screen when audio playback is available. I am using html 5  tag for audio playback. Please let me know if there is any other way to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an event listener to the 'canplaythrough' event on the audio element. Register a callback which displays the current text and plays the audio once this is the case.

There isn't actually an event available which fires when media has loaded completely; canplaythrough is just an estimate by the browser that it will play without interruptions bases on the amount that is buffered and the current download speed. This isn't exactly foolproof but it's the best option available.